# Is there a name for the data structure in which you use a contiguous vector of objects as a kind of pool?

Tags: design-patterns, data-structures, terminology

Say you need a collection of objects such that

1. You don't care what order they are in.
2. You want to be able to add and delete items in amortized constant time.
3. You want the collection to be layed out in memory contiguously.

Now, if it wasn't for 3. you could use a hash set. But with 3. the obvious implementation is using a resizable array, like an `std::vector` in C++, and do inserts by adding to the back and deletes by swapping the back item into the slot you want to delete and shortening the size of array by 1. As pointed out in comments, to get random access deletes, by ID say, you also need to maintain as part of the data structure a hash table keeping track of what is where.

My main question is does this data structure have a name? It seems related to a "[pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_(computer_science))" but the term pool is the name of a pattern not of a data structure. Also there is the term "[slab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation)" but this seems to be about a kind of allocator only.

Comment: Usually, using a contiguous vector as an allocation pool is done with a "free list" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list), which doesn't require swapping.  What kind of searches/accesses are you doing on this collection that can tolerate the swap?

Comment: if you need to test for containment and/or find by ID you can pair the above with a hashtable from ID to location in the collection which you maintain in the data structure across inserts and deletes, but I didnt want to muddy up the question with that idea. As i describe it is useful if you only ever need all of the items or if you need a partiuclar item so infrequently that O(n) searching for it does not matter.

Comment: Another use case for this data structure is generating a random member in constant time.

Comment: Yeah, the only times I've used this technique, it was as a random-order queue.  I've never heard a name for it.